# Reading Files with LOOP in Bash Script?

Tags: bash, text-processing

I hope someone can explain to me what's happening in this situation and how to solve it.

I am trying a simple thing: **to read each row from a text file with loop**.

This is the text file content that I am working on:

```
aaaa   aaaa a aa
bb bbbbb bbbbb    b
cccccccc          c                              c      c
```

NOTE: This is a simple file, just to test the concept. The main text file I am working have around 140MB, with a positional layout for each field.

This is my bash script content:

```bsh
FILE=./text.txt

awk '{ print }' $FILE | while read ROW; do
    echo $ROW
done
```

I am getting each row from the file, but this is the result:

```
aaaa aaaa a aa
bb bbbbb bbbbb b
cccccccc c c c
```

As you can see, the extra white spaces are being remove from the ouput.

I am trying to test this script using `awk`, but I already tried with `cat` and `stdout` and had the same result:

```bsh
FILE=./text.txt

# cat
cat $FILE | while read ROW; do
    echo $ROW
done

##########

# stdout
while read ROW; do
    echo $ROW
done < $FILE
```

I also tried using `for loop`:

```bsh
for ROW in $(awk '{ print }' $FILE); do
    echo $ROW
    echo "---"
done
```

But this was the result, each row content was split by the white spaces:

```
aaaa
---
aaaa
---
a
---
aa
---
bb
---
bbbbb
---
bbbbb
---
b
---
cccccccc
---
c
---
c
---
c
---
```

As I mentioned before, the main text file have positional fields, that's why I need all row characters, even if they are extra white spaces.

I was wondering if someone can explain to me why the extra white spaces were removed and how to print/work row full content (with any extra white space)?

Comment: `echo $ROW` should be `echo "$ROW"`- see [bash - When is double-quoting necessary?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/68748/65304). Also you likely want `IFS= read -r ROW` rather than just `read ROW`.

Comment: That's the answer ^^^^^^^^ (steeldriver). Arguments are different with quotes.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys for the help!!!

It worked =D.

I will pay attention to quotes from now on.

Thanks again